# Contact form working in local but not online

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a contact form on my website. The website in question was created using Next Js and deployed on Vercel.

The contact form locally works fine and I get confirmation mails from those who fill out the form, whereas in the "online" version it does not work and I get this error: 405 method POST not allowed.

What should I do to solve this problem?

I leave below the code of the contact page and the code of the api/contact.js page

**Contact page**

````
import React, { useRef } from "react"; 
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Link from "next/link";

const Contact1 = () => {
  const {
    register,
    reset,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    mode: 'onBlur',
    reValidateMode: 'onBlur'
  });

  // Enum for our statuses
  const contactStatuses = {
    loading: 'loading',
    submitted: 'submitted',
    error: 'error'
  };

  // Status of what's happening or happened in the component
  const [status, setStatus] = useState();

  // Our onSubmit function, which is called from react-hook-form handleSubmit
  // react-hook-form handleSubmit will pass our onSubmit the data object and event
  const onSubmit = async (data, e) => {
    // Used to Abort a long running fetch.
    const abortLongFetch = new AbortController();
    // Abort after 7 seconds.
    const abortTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => abortLongFetch.abort(), 7000);

    // Don't want to actually submit the form
    e.preventDefault();

    // Loading
    setStatus(contactStatuses.loading);

    // You can change this fetch URL to a bad url to see the .catch() block hit
    // Example: '/api/contact-bad'
    await fetch('/api/contact', {
      signal: abortLongFetch.signal,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          // If we got an 'ok' response from fetch, clear the AbortController timeout
          clearTimeout(abortTimeoutId);
          return res.json();
        }
        // If the response was anything besides 'ok', throw an error to hit our .catch() block
        throw new Error('Whoops! Error sending email.');
      })
      .then((res) => {
        // On a successful search, set the status to 'submitted' and reset the fields
        setStatus(contactStatuses.submitted);
        reset();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // There was an error, catch it and set the status to 'error'
        setStatus(contactStatuses.error);
      });
  };

  // Email Form Validation RegEx used in client-side validation with react-hook-form
  const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;

  // Standard error message for required form fields
  const requiredFieldErrorMsg = 'This field is required';


  return ( ... );
};

export default Contact1; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the api/contact page
**Contact api**

````
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    res.status(405).send({ message: 'Only POST requests allowed' })
    return
  }
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

const { name, email, subject, message } = req.body;
 
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  /**
   * First we setup a 'transporter' which contains our credentials.
   * I'm sure there is a better way to protect this information but for 
   * now it's stuffed in environment variables
   */
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_HOST,
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
    user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_PASS
    }
  });

  /**
   * Then we can call the transporter.sendMail method, which will actually 
   * send the email. There are two options on sendMail, you can use a 
   * callbacak function, or if a callback is not specified, it returns 
   * a Promise.
   */
  transporter
    .sendMail({
      from: email, // sender address
      to: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_SEND_TO, // list of receivers
      subject: subject, // Subject line
      text: message, // plain text body
      html: `<div>${message} <br /><br />Thank you,<br />${name}</div>`
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // On a successful email send
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ error: false, emailSent: true, errors: [], response });
      resolve();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ error: true, emailSent: false, errors: [error] });
      reject(new Error(error));
    });
});
}```
````